# Create a pagination with Github API and express

Tags: node.js, express, pagination, github-api

I'm currently creating one of my first small apps in Express and Node, which allows me to browse through all the repository from github, using their API. It all works fine for now, but of course some of the keywords i put into the search are giving me 17k or more result back, depending on how popular my search term is. The problem now is:

How to create a pagination? By default, the API returns 30 results PER PAGE, which can be changed to my liking, if i only want one result per page.The information, how many pages are available, can be found in the HTTP header, as far as i understand.
I understand from their docs that i need to extract the link information from the http header like so:

```
curl -I "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris"
```

results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2018 14:55:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 170353
...
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
Link: <https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=pokemon&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=pokemon&page=34>; rel="last"
```

Interesting for me is the link part, it gives me information about the next page, and how many there are in general. All the tuts i found right now are based results from a database and extracted info coming from tables or schemas. I just don't quite understand how I parse the curl information into express now, or what other possibilites I have. I tried with req.headers, which gave me

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/github',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7' }
```

which is not quite what i was hoping for.

My current route look likes this:

```
app.get('/github/results', function (req, res) {
var query = req.query.gitHubsearch;
var options = {headers: {'User-Agent':'request'}};
var pageSize = 25;
var apiCall = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=' + query + '&order=desc+&per_page=' + pageSize;
request.get(apiCall, options, function (error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var githubData = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(req.headers);
      res.render("./github/results", {githubData: githubData});
    }
  });
});
```

I hope someone can give me a hint in what direction i have to look, or how i would create this kind of pagination now in NodeJS.

Comment: why not using [octonode](https://github.com/pksunkara/octonode) library which process [pagination](https://github.com/pksunkara/octonode#pagination) for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `req.header` which is using the request object of the request being made to your API, not the response from the github API call.

If you look at your `app.get` line you define req and res as per the express standard. This relates to the request being made to your server. The call to the request library then makes a HTTP call which then calls the callback function which populates `error, response, body` with details of your call up to github.

If you do `console.log(response.headers)` you should find the `link` item in there which you can access through `response.headers.link`.

It looks like you've just gotten a tiny bit confused between the request and response objects of your API vs the ones from the GitHub API is all. Here's some simple code which you should be able to run and see what you're expecting.

```
const request = require('request');

app.get('/github/result', function(req, res) {
    const endpoint = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + query + "&order=desc+&per_page=" + pageSize;

    request.get(
      endpoint,
      { headers: { "User-Agent": "request" } },
      function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res.headers);
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help. Yeah, i think i just confused a bit ^^ Btw why do you use const instead of var? should i read up on that before continuing?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see that could be confusing. In the latest version of JavaScript (ES6) (recent versions of node have this such as 8.x and 9.x) they introduced "let" and "const". You'll be totally fine with "var", but let and const are now generally preferred. Check this post out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable. Further to that, const is the same as "let" but you can't reassign it. So `const str = 'yes'; str = 'no';` will generate an error on `str = no;`.

Comment: Don't spend too long confusing yourself with those bits though, that concept is quite quick to pick up so you should be fine but JS is a deep hole of new things happening every day. It's better to learn the basics first, and then move into areas like this just for your own sanity!

Comment: alright, i heard about them briefly, but I guess i should go over the basics first! At least I get my links now from the header, now time to find out how to consume the information properly! Thanks again!